# Animating UIBezier to get a live curve

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I am trying to create a simple line graph which is being updated live. Some kind of *seismograph* .

I was thinking about `UIBezierPath`, by only moving a point on the y-axis according to an input var, I can create a line moving on the time axis.

The problem is that you have to "push" the previous points to free up space for the new ones (so the graph goes from left to right).

What can I try next?

```
 var myBezier = UIBezierPath()
        myBezier.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        myBezier.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0))
        myBezier.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 50, y: 100))
        myBezier.closePath()
        UIColor.blackColor().setStroke()
        myBezier.stroke()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct: you need to push the previous points. Either divide the total width of the graph so it becomes increasingly scaled but retains all data, or drop the first point each time you add a new one to the end. You'll need to store an array of these points and recreate the path each time. Something like:

```
//Given...
let graphWidth: CGFloat = 50
let graphHeight: CGFloat = 20
var values: [CGFloat] = [0, 4, 3, 2, 6]

//Here's how you make your curve...
var myBezier = UIBezierPath()
myBezier.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: values.first!))
for (index, value) in values.enumerated() {
    let point = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(index)/CGFloat(values.count) * graphWidth, y: value/values.max()! * graphHeight)
    myBezier.addLineToPoint(point)
}
UIColor.blackColor().setStroke()
myBezier.stroke()

//And here's how you'd add a point...
values.removeFirst() //do this if you want to scroll rather than squish
values.append(8)
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Can you elaborate on the "add point to curve" ? how you add a point(not a line? )

Comment: @Curnelious: I've edited in your original `UIBezierPath` code so you can see how this new `values` array translates into your old `UIBezierPath`. It's pretty similar to what you were doing.

Comment: thanks thats great, but when I think about it , it would be a very flickery graph which will be drawn every time again like an old oscilloscope. I was searching for a way to simply create a smooth line curve live and I could not find anything simple. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Depends how often "every time" is... it's pretty standard to redraw 60 times per second to achieve the illusion of smooth animation. If your data is coming in that quickly, this solution will appear smooth.

Comment: Yea I am trying it now, for some reason its not showing anything.. I get many CGContext errors.

Comment: even your edit still gives error, and you can't see any graph

Comment: @Curnelious: This is only the outline of how to produce such a graph; the code must of course be placed in an appropriate `CGContext`... if you aren't familiar with custom drawing, you should look into that next. (Perhaps you will be overriding `drawRect()` of a custom view class?)

Comment: Yes I use a custom view class, I am not sure I get you but I will have to learn how to make it work.